How to resolve memory heap fatal error in angular
Currently, I have a fatal error displaying when I start my project. I have tried all possible solutions, so please let me know how can I resolve this.
ng serve
⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[27248:03EFBAA8]   311252 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1014.2 (1026.2) -> 1013.6 (1027.5) MB, 2168.8 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.074, current mu = 0.009) alloc


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

C:\Users\Nimra\Desktop\angular\QA\enableu-app>ng serve
⠴ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[22980:03E894E0]   171563 ms: Mark-sweep 1016.1 (1032.6) -> 1014.0 (1034.1) MB, 1007.2 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.127, current mu = 0.023) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[22980:03E894E0]   173624 ms: Mark-sweep 1018.1 (1042.1) -> 1016.0 (1043.3) MB, 2038.4 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.051, current mu = 0.011) allocation fai

<--- Last few GCs --->

[12044:03E79450]      111 ms: Mark-sweep 1.0 (3.3) -> 1.0 (3.3) MB, 3.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.772, current mu = 0.044) allocation failure GC in old space requested
[12044:03E79450]      115 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1.0 (3.3) -> 0.9 (3.3) MB, 3.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.647, current mu = 0.185) last resort GC in old space requested
[12044:03E79450]      119 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 0.9 (2.3) -> 0.9 (3.3) MB, 4.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.463, current mu = 0.014) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tried these solutions without success:

Uninstall node, cli everything, download it again, and start
Update npm and everything not working
Reclone my project from main project.
Tried by increasing memory size by commands




I had to include the node memory size in the actual script i run in package.json:
"buildLarge": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production"

then i run npm run buildLarge from the cli
This is in an angular 15 project but might work for you
